# RDL reports do not work in Mobile Devices in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, mobile, rdl

RSViewerPage.aspx does not show all RDL reports in mobile devices.(IOS, Android)

I have On-Premises SharePoint Farm application. It means I can change RSViewerPage.aspx if there is any need.

Is there any configuration or trick to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://placko.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/sharepoint-bi-and-mobile-bi-on-sql-server-platform/][1]

**Three-server SharePoint testing environment:**

Hardware configuration of a three-server SharePoint 2013 testing environment:
1. Windows Domain Controller:
OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition
CPU: 1x
Memory: 1GB RAM
HDD: 32GB
2. SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition (or Business Intelligence Edition):
OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition
CPU: 4x
Memory: 8GB RAM
HDD: 1x 80GB (OS and SQL Server installation) and 1x 40GB (database installation, SSD)
3. SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition:
OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition
CPU: 4x
Memory: 12GB RAM
HDD: 1x 80GB
Software installation and configuration:
1. Windows Domain Controller: Step-by-Step Guide for Setting Up Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller

2. SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition: Installation for SQL Server 2012
3. SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Edition: SharePoint 2013: Installation Step by Step
   Secure Store Service: Configure the Secure Store Service in SharePoint 2013
   Plan the Secure Store Service in SharePoint Server 2013
   note: Plan for Kerberos authentication in SharePoint 2013
   Excel Services: Configure Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013
   Data authentication for Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2013
   Use EffectiveUserName with Excel Services (SharePoint Server 2013)
   PerformancePoint Services: Configure PerformancePoint Services (SharePoint Server 2013)
   note: ERROR – The data source provider for data sources of type ‘ADOMD.NET’ is not registered. Please contact an administrator. PerformancePoint Services error code 10115.
   note: SOLUTION – on SQL Server you need to install SQL Server 2008 R2 ADOMD.NET (i.e. to downgrade ADOMD.NET from 2012 to 2008 R2)
   PowerPivot (for SharePoint): PowerPivot for SharePoint (SSAS)
   Reporting Services (integrated mode): Install Reporting Services SharePoint Mode for SharePoint 2013
   View and Explore Native Mode Reports Using SharePoint Web Parts (SSRS)
   note: ERROR – Failed to extract the cab file in the solution.
   note: SOLUTION – instead of installing the version 2012 you must install the cab file for SQL Server 2008 R2 that is located at the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Reporting Services\SharePoint\ (or directly for download here: RSWebParts.cab)
   PowerView for OLAP (multidimensional mode): Power View for Multidimensional Models

In a few bullets below, there are described the results of my investigation about some possibilities for mobile BI solutions based on the SQL Server platform.

Mobile BI (iPad/iPhone, Android, Windows 8/Phone devices) platform:

1. IIS:
   SSRS:
   iPad: Safari/Chrome/Opera – NO, Mercury (Chrome and Firefox alternative) – NO, FF/IE – not supported
   either to use a native application from app store, e.g.:
   Mobi Reports Pro by Mobi Weave, Inc. (note: very good solution – I recommend it’s use)
   SSRS Report Viewer Pro by By Ororo a.s. (note: iPad only)
   or to use Remote Desktop Services/Terminal Services (Windows Server) instead of native application (note: in addition one CAL per user)
   Android: FF – OK, Chrome/Opera – NO, Safari/IE – not supported
   Windows 8: IE – OK, alternative – FF, Chrome/Opera – NO, Safari – not supported on tablet?
2. SharePoint 2013:
   Excel Services:
   iPad: Safari – OK (note: slicers – OK), alternatives – Chrome/Mercury (Chrome and Firefox alternative), Opera – NO, FF/IE – not supported
   Android: FF – OK (note: slicers – NO), Chrome/Opera/(Built-in Browser/Dolphin) – NO, Safari/IE – not supported
   Windows 8: IE – OK, alternatives – FF/Chrome/Opera, Safari – not supported
   PerformancePoint Services (Dashboards):
   OLAP/Excel Services:
   iPad: Safari – OK (note: slicers – OK), alternatives – Chrome/Mercury (Chrome and Firefox alternative), Opera – NO, FF/IE – not supported
   Android: FF – OK (note: slicers – NO), Chrome/Opera/(Built-in Browser/Dolphin) – NO, Safari/IE – not supported
   Windows 8: IE – OK, alternative – FF, Chrome/Opera – OK (note: zoom – NO), Safari – not supported
   SSRS:
   iPad: Safari/Chrome/Opera – NO, Mercury (Chrome and Firefox alternative) – NO, FF/IE – not supported
   Android: FF – OK, Chrome/Opera/(Built-in Browser/Dolphin) – NO, Safari/IE – not supported
   Windows 8: IE – OK, alternative – FF, Chrome/Opera – NO, Safari – not supported on tablet?
   PowerPivot/PowerView: the output is rendered in Silverlight
   iPad: SL – not supported on iOS (note: SL is available only for Windows and Mackintosh)
   Android: SL – not supported
   Windows 8: IE – OK, alternatives – FF/Chrome/Opera (note: scroll – NO), Safari – not supported
3. OWA 2013 (Office Web Apps):
   Deploy Office Web Apps Server
   Configure SharePoint 2013 to use Office Web Apps
   4.a) 3rd party developer tools/platforms:
   Build cross-platform iOS, Android, Mac and Windows apps with C# and .NET by Xamarin
   UIFramework for .NET by ComponentArt
   Data Visualization for Visual Studio by ComponentArt
   4.b) 3rd party ready-to-use solutions:
   Datazen – Mobile BI for Windows 8, iPad/iPhone and Android by ComponentArt
   Tableau Server by Tableau Software (note: I recommend it’s use)
   iPad: web browsers – OK and native free app – OK
   Android: web browsers – OK and native free app – OK
   Windows 8: web browsers – OK (note: a native app isn’t available)
   Mobi Reports Pro – BI for SSRS on iPad and iPhone by Mobi Weave
   Mobi Office – Mobile Content Management by Mobi Weave